# VS 2010: How do I get "next tab", "prev tab" keyboard shortcut working?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

**How do I get "next tab", "prev tab" keyboard shortcuts to work in Visual Studios 2010?**

(For a more precise description of the functionality I need please see the firefox/chrome/etc and how they do their "ctrl-pgdn" and "ctrl-pgup" keyboard shortcuts).

This should be extrememly easy... and yet I can't seem to figure it out.

---

**NOTE:**

I do know that there is a "ctrl-tab" that is similar... but it only scrolls through the "most recently used list" which is different. I don't care about "the most recently used list". I just want to go to the right/left tab.

Comment: You have to use the keyboard shortcuts: <C-Tab> and <C-S-Tab>. Those two keyboard shortcuts scroll through the most recently used tabs... which is similar to what i was asking but not the same

Comment: Thanks. I only managed to assign shortcurs for View.NextTab and View.PreviousTab in options, but it seems is only applicable for tabs in... oh, well, views like Solution Explorer or Find Results.

Comment: http://www.myfreewallpapers.net/cartoons/pages/dilbert-fist-of-death.shtml

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You should map the `Window.NextDocumentWellTab` and not `View.NextTab` and remove it from any other functions its assigned to. Only mapping it will not work, you also need to unmap from anything else its being used on, apparently.

This is what my keyboard configuration looks like:
[image: Keyboard options]

Looked into this some more, and it turns you need to install the [Productivity Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/). That gives you that NextDocumentWellTab function.

Comment: I just opened VS 2010 --> there is no "Window.NextDocumentWellTab" under Window --> options --> keyboard.

Comment: Doesn't work on Visual Studio 2012 though.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist what does "doesnt work" mean?

Comment: In Visual Studio 2013, it is Window.NextTab and Window.PreviousTab. NOTE: I have Productivity Power Tools 2013 installed. I'm not sure if that is relevant.

Comment: In VS 2013, you need to Remove the shortcuts for "Edit.ViewBottom" and "Edit.ViewTop" in order to get the "Ctrl-PageUp" and "Ctrl-PageDown" functionality.

Answer (score 29):

Under Visual Studio 2010 Professional, this keyboard shortcut goes by the name `Window.PreviousDocumentWindow` and `Window.NextDocumentWindow`.

**Important Note**: By default, <kbd>Ctrl-PgUp</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-PgDown</kbd> are assigned to `Edit.ViewTop` and `Edit.ViewBottom` respectively, so **make sure to remove the existing keyboard assignment** before trying out your new assignment. If you don't, the keyboard commands you enter will continue to be interpreted as the most "specific" shortcut (`Edit.ViewTop` or `Edit.ViewBottom`) since you're most likely trying this out in the Edit view!

Comment: Works after resolving existing double assignment! In VS2015 Window.NextDocumentWindow seems to be the same as Window.NextTab (and same for Window.Previous* functionality), although they have different default shortcuts assigned.

EDIT: actually one cycles through visible tabs, the other through open windows / documents ...

Comment: Still the same in VS 2015. I had to remove two shortcuts from Edit.ViewTop / Edit.ViewBottom before Window.NextDocumentWindow / Window.PreviousDocumentWindow got precendence.